# Show data from a specific row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a simple bug tracking tool.
When you create a new project, all the info you fill in in the form, gets stored in the database.

When you create the new project you get redirected to a unique project page.
On top of the page it shows the name of the project, but it's not the name of the project I just created, it always shows the name of the first project in the MySQL table.

How can I show the name of the project I just created?

With this query I retrieve the data from the database.

```
$query = "SELECT CONCAT(name) 
AS name FROM projects";
$result = @mysql_query ($query)
```

With this I show the project name, but it always shows the name of the first record in the table.

```
    <?php 
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
        echo '<h5>' . $row['name'] . '</h5>'; 
    ?>
```

It isn't yet SQL Injection prove and is far from complete... But I'm really struggling with this problem.

Comment: When you retrieve the data from the database, you must filter it with a `where` clause.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but please don't use mysql_* functions, use MySQLi, and please don't suppress errors with @.... That said, make sure your table has an `id` auto_increment column. You can get the id of the most recently inserted project by accessing the `insert_id` property of the `MySQLi` object or `mysql_insert_id()` ( I think).

Answer (score 1):

You need an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field on your table for a unique identifier (at least, you really should). Then you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$sql = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');

$sql->query('INSERT INTO `projects` (`name`) VALUES ("Test Project");');
$projectID = $sql->insert_id; // Returns the auto_increment field value of the last insert query performed
// So this assumes you have a field in your table called "id" in this example

$res = $sql->query('SELECT CONCAT(`name`) AS `name` FROM `projects` WHERE `id` = '.$projectID.';');

if ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<h5>'.$row['name'].'</h5>';
}
?>
```

Since you were calling for a redirect to the unique project page, you should have something like this: `header("Location: project.php?id=$projectID");`

Then, on project.php, you can attempt to fetch the project with the query above, only your query's WHERE clause should be something like:

```
'`id` = '.intval($_GET['id']).';'
```

Technically, you could pass all the project info along to the next page as a request or a session cookie and save yourself a query altogether. Just make sure you keep the `id` handy so it's easy to update the record.

Comment: When you fill in the form, it will post the info to the project.class.php file

Comment: $name     = $_POST['name'];
 $descr      = $_POST['description']; 
 $leader      = $_POST['leader']; 
 $email       = $_POST['email'];
 
 $sql="INSERT INTO projects (name, description, leader, email, registration_date)
 VALUES ('$name', '$descr', '$leader', '$email', NOW())";
 $projectID = $sql->insert_id;
 $result = mysql_query($sql); 
 
 if($result){
 header('Location: ../projectpage.php?id='.mysql_insert_id());
 }
 else {
 echo "There is something wrong. Try again later.";
 }
 
 mysql_close();

Comment: then you get redirected to the project page, there I wan't to retrieve the data, so shoud I use the SELECT there?

Comment: Yes, you should connect on the projectpage.php page and then use the SELECT query. A note about your code: you have to escape your input to protect against SQL injection, e.g. `$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);`. Also, I advise again that you look into the MySQLi class instead of `mysql_` functions, as they're officially deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. If you prefer procedural programming, you can just replace `mysql_` functions with `mysqli_` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ORDER BY`.

```
$query = "SELECT CONCAT(name) 
AS name FROM projects ORDER BY id DESC";
```

This would show the most recent project (assuming you have an ID column).

However, a much better way is to have an ID variable on the page.

```
$query = "SELECT CONCAT(name) 
AS name FROM projects WHERE id=?";
```